# How to remove left margin of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to use every pixel of my small 1366x768 laptop screen and I've noticed this left margin, why is it?? how to get rid of it?

[image: Left Margin]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Hot Settings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotSettings) extension to hide editor margins.

Comment: Upvoted. The keyword is "Margin", thank you for the reminder. Whether the answer is helpful, I prefer not to install third-party plugins, just use the built-in functionality of VS.