# White left margin in Visual Studio Editor 2019

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way that I can get rid of this white left margin of the Visual Studio 2019 editor?
[Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qIR6.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33144047/reduce-left-margin-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Thank you for the link.As far as I can understand this margin is used  by the code analysis tool and cannot disabled through the options panel

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66035681/how-to-remove-left-margin-of-visual-studio

Comment: Thank you, I need to explore in more depth the available extensions